# How to detect double clicks or long clicks on points in Highcharts charts?

Tags: events, highcharts

Highcharts offers the opportunity to detect clicks on chart points, but is it possible
to detect other events, such as the double click or mousedown event?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can add your votes and comments to a feature request here:  http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/3159039-support-dblclick-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but in a different way. In Highcharts you can add event to each element using [element.on](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Element.on). For example:

```js
    chart.series[0].data[0].graphic.on('dblclick', function() {
       //callback here
    });
```

And [simple jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/3bQne/325/) for you. Good thing is that you can add to all elements, and make sure work in all browsers.

Comment: First, I advice to read about closures in javascript. Then use `pointdata.select(true)` not `point.select(true);`

Answer (score 5):

Each component only supports certain events, for example the Chart component will detect `addSeries`, `click`, `load`, `redraw`, and `selection`. I don't believe this set is extensible, so you can't capture a different event like `mousedown`.

You could try to inspect the source of your page and attach listeners to the elements that HighCharts generates, but this would be an undocumented work-around and would be liable to break in future releases. In addition, if you have to support < IE9 you would need handlers for both SVG and VML generated markup.

You can get creative with some events. Here's an example of detecting a double click using a click handler:

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gLBAF/)**

```js
var clickDetected = false;

// create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        events: {
            click: function(event) {
                if(clickDetected) {
                    alert ('x: '+ event.xAxis[0].value +', y: '+ event.yAxis[0].value);
                    clickDetected = false;
                } else {
                    clickDetected = true;
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        clickDetected = false;
                    }, 500); 
                }
            }
        }        
    },
   ...
```