# Integrate highcharts-custom-events with React

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I've installed a highcharts-custom-events package to handle custom events(dblclick).

like the code below

```
var Highcharts = require('highcharts'),
HighchartsCustomEvents = require('highcharts-custom-events')(Highcharts);
```

But after adding this code, even the existing click is also not working.
Please help me to implement custom events to react.

Comment: Looks fine so far, so you could provide the part of your code, where you define and use the events.

Comment: point: {
          events: {
            //dblclick
            click: (e) => {
              console.log("inside click")
            },
            dblclick: (e) => {
              console.log("inside double click")
            }
          },

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with implemented custom events in Highcharts with using react wrapper.

```
import CustomEvents from "highcharts-custom-events";

CustomEvents(Highcharts);
//require('highcharts-custom-events')(Highcharts);
```

Both above ways work - import and require.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-1rtxl

If this wouldn't help - could you reproduce your case in the online editor which I could work on?

Comment: Hi thanks for ur answer, i need to apply both click and double click on the same column.
ie. one action one click and another on Dbl click on the same point.

Comment: It is a regular behaviour that click and dbclick events triggers each other. See: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/oL0ynh2x/ To make it work separately you will need to delay the function to detect which one was triggered. Here is my idea how to do it: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-rnshm On the Internet you can easily find other approaches

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem using this lib, it was breaking the standard single click, I believe this is a duplicate post from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266454/highcharts-double-click-event) one.

On that post there is a function implementation of double click, that solution also breakes the single click, the thing is that you can add the single click as a condition inside double click function:

Fisrt define the settings:

```js
            var doubleClicker = {
                clickedOnce : false,
                timer : null,
                timeBetweenClicks : 400
            };
```

Then define a 'double click reset' function in case the double click is not fast enough and a double click callback:

```js
            // call to reset double click timer
            var resetDoubleClick = function() {
              clearTimeout(doubleClicker.timer);
              doubleClicker.timer = null;
              doubleClicker.clickedOnce = false;
            };

            // the actual callback for a double-click event
            var ondbclick = function(e, point) {
              if (point && point.x) {
                  // Do something with point data
              }
            };
```

Highcharts settings example

```js
    series: [{
      point: {
        events: {

          click: function(e) {
            if (doubleClicker.clickedOnce === true && doubleClicker.timer) {
              resetDoubleClick();
              ondbclick(e, this);
            } else {
              doubleClicker.clickedOnce = true;
              doubleClicker.timer = setTimeout(function(){
                resetDoubleClick();
              }, doubleClicker.timeBetweenClicks);
            }
          }

        }
       }
    }]
```