# JavaScript - Highcharts : How to prevent double click?

Tags: javascript, events, highcharts, click, double-click

I need to prevent a double click event on a highchart series (point). I checked the Highchart documentation and it doesn't seem to support doubleclick event. Does anyone know how to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Might be able to use an extension to then disable double clicking:
http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events

Answer (score 0):

see this [How to detect double clicks or long clicks on points in Highcharts charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403261/how-to-detect-double-clicks-or-long-clicks-on-points-in-highcharts-charts)

custom event plugin available at
http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events

Comment: I was able to implement the first solution you linked. (Not the plug). On the side not, it still fires the first click event though, but I'm still working on it.